# "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" with nginx, PostgreSQL and Mono on Ubuntu MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, ubuntu, nginx, mono

/Edit I  done the suggestion of [the answer to the question mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872394) to give access rights to the registry as follows:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/mono/registry
sudo chmod uog+rw /usr/local/etc/mono/registry
```

This did not help, as the bad gateway problem only appears *after* having given access to the registry with the above commands (before that I got the registry error).

**Question**:
I want to deploy a MVC 4 app running on Mono runtime with nginx to an Ubuntu server of Azure. By selecting such a Ubuntu server and running an installer script I managed to have a default web application running and visible on oogstplanner.cloudapp.net. The installer worked as follows:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/mindbar/install-mono/raw/master/install-nginx- 
mono.sh && sudo chmod +x install-nginx-mono.sh && ./install-nginx-mono.sh
```

The script installed nginx and mono and setup the nginx.conf and other configuration files.

What I then did was remove this installation, installed postgresql and setup the database, and replaced the files in $HOME/www/ with my own MVC 4 web application which works locally by copying it there. Then when running it I see a

[image: >502 Bad Gateway]

error.

The log file /var/log/nginx/error.log says (for the first and subsequent requests):

> 2015/04/03 14:24:36 [error] 1305#0: *6 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: my.ip.207, server: localhost, request: "GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "oogstplanner.cloudapp.net"
>   2015/04/03 14:26:05 [error] 1305#0: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my.ip.207, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "oogstplanner.cloudapp.net"
>   2015/04/03 14:29:24 [error] 1305#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my.ip.58, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "oogstplanner.cloudapp.net" 
>  (...)

So it does see that it needs to go to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl! Something *is* working.

When I copy back a default app it works again.

Configuration:

- [Here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/8b1f361ef38e44b6dc30).
- [Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/mono-default](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/daf7f433672b453f68cb) (same for sites-enabled/monodefault)

/edit I have a strong suspicion that it has to do with the PostgreSQL database. This is because I just rebooted the server, and saw this NullReferenceException being thrown by NauckIt.PostgreSQLProvider:

[image: What I saw after a reboot]

This error always happens locally *once*, and then after a refresh the app works. But on the server the app does not work, but after not having the PostgreSQL provider throw a NullReferenceException I get the 502 error. So that is why I think the bad gateway might come from the PostgreSQL connection.

/Edit2 The plot thickens: when I look into the database I see (some) sessions being created in the Sessions table. I don't see any logic when that happens and have been unable to create a new one. But there has been a connection from the web app to the database sometimes.

Here is the PostgreSQL log after a restart (at 14:25:23) and navigating to the website via a browser (at 14:24:36):

> 2015-04-03 14:24:23 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>   2015-04-03 14:24:23 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
>   2015-04-03 14:24:23 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
>   2015-04-03 14:24:36 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

According to a reddit user:

> 502 Bad Gateway is an HTTP status code and cannot be returned by postgres because postgres doesn't speak HTTP. Similarly, NullReferenceException is a Mono exception and isn't thrown by postgres, so that's not a postgres problem either. Your application is attempting to send some data to postgres but crashes before it can finish doing so. This is an application problem, not a postgres problem. Hope this helps.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

PS I have all steps I've taken documented under the Deployment part in a [README](https://github.com/erooijak/zaaikalender/blob/master/README.md) file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to the path "/etc/mono/registry" is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872394/access-to-the-path-etc-mono-registry-is-denied)

Comment: a NullReferenceException is always a programming defect that a developer has introduced, so you should file a bug or contribute a patch

Comment: The error is happening because something is unexpectedly null inside `PgSessionStateStoreProvider` - looking at the source at http://dev.nauck-it.de/attachments/5/PgSessionStateStoreProvider.cs I'm guessing it's `item`, but without a line number in the stack trace it's only a guess, and I don't know enough to say why this would be happening - just posting here in case it triggers something.

Comment: I would suggest testing your application under Windows VM with IIS + postgreSql, that will be easier to debug your own application errors/exceptions. Once it is done, then you can think of deploying over linux. Also you need to log your exceptions using log4net or any other library and make sure all exceptions are logged including AppDomain UnhandledException event. nginx is a proxy server, it is difficult to test app behind proxy, I would suggest first test app under localhost with direct access to webserver.

Comment: @MuratYıldız It was a clean server with a fresh install. How does your answer explain the fact that using a "Hello world" app does work? Something with PostgreSQL? Maybe you can elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be caused from originally disabling the http port and allowing only https. If have not been enabled, try to enable http port, only allow requests through 127.0.0.1. In addition to this also check the "*timeout*" values in the configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks. Could you specify where I can configure those settings? On Azure or in the Nginx settings? And if the latter, which file? And does this explain why it does work with an application without a database?

Comment: Please check the following links: http://serverfault.com/questions/632527/upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from-upstre

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254031 

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream

Answer (score 1):

Same error can appear in case if you are using MS SQL Server and found some exceptions in your application log, try to turn off `Trusted_Connection` option in SQL server connection string:

```
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=db;User Id=dbuser;password=dbpassword;Trusted_Connection=false"
```